# Error while updating the database for the second time with php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to update my database named **publication** with a form as created in **data.html**. And the file **pubupdate.php** is used to update the database which is linked through **data.html**.

While updating for the first time it is updating the database but with **projcont1 = NULL,projcont2= NULL, volume= NULL, startpage with endpage** and **endpage= NULL**. Rest all are updated fine.
**ABOVE GOT SOLVED**

While updating for the next time, table project and journal are not being updated at all while other table is getting updated and giving following error.

Notice: Undefined index: projid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: papertitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: jtitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 30
Strange Error

I am posting both the codes, please help me out as I have already spent hell lot of time in debugging it. I am new to programming this.

***data.html***

```
<html>

<title> Publication v.0.0.1 </title>


 <div align = "center">

 <form action = "pubupdate.php" method = "post">
 <p>Paper Type :<br> <select name="papertype"></p>
 <option value="">Paper Type...</option>
 <option value="journaltype">Journal</option>
 <option value="conferencetype">Conference</option>
 </select>
 <br></br>
 First Author : <br><input type = "text" name = "firstauthor">
 <br></br>
 Co-Authors : <br><input type = "text" name = "coauthor">
 <br></br>
 Title :  <br><input type = "text" name = "ptitle">
 <br></br>
 Abstract :  <br><textarea name = "abstract" rows = 10 cols = 50></textarea>
 <br></br>
 Conference / Journal Name :  <br><input type = "text" name = "namecon">
 <br></br>
 Conference / Publication Date : <br> <input type = "text" name = "date">
 <br></br>
 Start Page No:  <br><input type = "text" name = "startpage">
 <br></br>
 End Page No: <br> <input type = "text" name = "endpage">
 <br></br>

 Area: <br> <input type = "text" name = "area">
 <br></br>

 Project Name 1 : <br> <input type = "text" name = "projname1">
<br></br>
 Project ID 1 : <br> <input type = "text" name = "projid1">
<br></br>
Contribution : <br> <select name="projcont1">
 <option value="">Contribution...</option>
 <option value="10">10 </option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 </select>
<br></br>

Project Name 2 : <br> <input type = "text" name = "projname2">
<br></br>
 Project ID 2 : <br> <input type = "text" name = "projid2">
<br></br>
Contribution :  <br> <select name="projcont2">
 <option value="">Contribution...</option>
 <option value="10">10  </option>
 </select>
<br></br>

ISSN : <br> <input type = "text" name = "issn">
<br></br> 
Impact Factor : <br> <input type = "text" name = "imfac">
<br></br> 
ISBN : <br> <input type = "text" name = "isbn">
<br></br> 
SCI/ SSCI/ AHCI :  <br><input type = "text" name = "sci">
<br></br> 
Location : <br><select name="location">
<option value="">Location...</option>
<option value="domestic">Domestic</option>
</select>   
<br></br> 
Issue :  <br><input type = "text" name = "issue">
<br></br> 
Volume :  <br><input type = "text" name = "volume">
<br></br> 


 Country : <br><select name="country">
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>

</select>
<br></br>


<input type ="submit" value ="Update this Publication List">

</form>
</div>
</html>
```

***pubupdate.php***

```
 <?php


 // Updating the values of Table "Paper"
 $typereg = $_POST['papertype'];
 $ptitlereg = $_POST['ptitle'];
 $fauthorreg = $_POST['firstauthor'];
 $coauthorreg = $_POST['coauthor'];
 $abstractreg = $_POST['abstract'];
 $nameconreg = $_POST['namecon'];
 $areareg = $_POST['area'];
 $datereg = $_POST['date'];
 $startpagereg = $_POST['startpage'];
 $endpagereg = $_POST['endpage'];
 $projidreg = $_POST['projid'];
 $countryreg = $_POST['country'];

 // Updating the values of Table "Project"
 $papertitlereg = $_POST['papertitle'];
 $projname1reg = $_POST['projname1'];
 $projid1reg = $_POST['projid1'];
 $projcont1reg = $_POST['projcont1'];
 $projname2reg = $_POST['projname2'];
 $projid2reg = $_POST['projid2'];
 $projcont2reg = $_POST['projcont2'];

 // Updating the values of Table "Journal"
 $issnreg = $_POST['issn'];
 $jtitlereg = $_POST['jtitle'];
 $imfacreg = $_POST['imfac'];
 $isbnreg = $_POST['isbn'];
 $scireg = $_POST['sci'];
 $locationreg = $_POST['location'];
 $issuereg = $_POST['issue'];
 $volumereg = $_POST['volume'];

 // Create Local variable
 $taken = "false";
 $database = "publication";
 $password = "";
 $username = "root";

 // Main if statement
 //if($userreg && $passreg){

// Connect to database
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect database");
@mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to connect");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `paper` VALUES('$typereg', '$ptitlereg','$fauthorreg','$coauthorreg','$abstractreg' ,'$nameconreg', '$areareg','$datereg', '$startpagereg', '$endpagereg','','$countryreg' )") or die("Strange Error");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `journal` VALUES('$issnreg', '','$imfacreg','$isbnreg','$scireg' ,'$locationreg', '$issuereg','$volumereg')") or die("Strange Error");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `project` VALUES( '','$projname1reg','$projid1reg','$projcont1reg' ,'$projname2reg', '$projid2reg','$projcont2reg')") or die("Strange Error");

echo "Account Created";

mysql_close($con);

header('Location: home.php');



 ?>
```

Comment: Please try use mysqli extension as mysql is in deprecating stage now.

Comment: It means I should change mysql with mysqli everywhere ?

Comment: Yes buddy. you need to do that

Comment: @user3363895 Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Review your html form, all notices thrown by PHP means those form variables are missing in your html form.

Comment: Errors are same but databse is not getting connected due to mysqli_connect thing.

Notice: Undefined index: endpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: papertitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: jtitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: volume in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\pubupdate.php on line 35
Unable to connect

Comment: @DexterHuindaI did that and it worked well but the problem remain same for the second time when I am updating it.

Comment: Again, the notices/warnings/errors you were receiving from php means you have those missing form field names in your HTML form. e.g. 'Undefined index projid' means it cannot find the counterpart form field with that name in your html form, review your form again, there should be something like <input type='text' name='projid'> somewhere. The same with the other errors you're getting.

Comment: @DexterHuinda Now the only error is the "Strange Error" for the second time updating. However when I restarted my system and updated then it worked fine and again I went for updating for the second time, it gave "Strange Error". And that error is due to som problem in third table "project" bcoz rest two tables are being updated as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I have added check whether a value is present or not, If a value is not present then 'NA' would be added, you can change this string if required. Below code will help you debug more.

```
<?php
//$userreg = isset() ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
//$passreg = isset() ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);

// Updating the values of Table "Paper"
$typereg =  isset($_POST['papertype']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['papertype']):"NA";
$ptitlereg = isset($_POST['ptitle']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ptitle']):"NA";
$fauthorreg = isset($_POST['firstauthor']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstauthor']):"NA";
$coauthorreg = isset($_POST['coauthor']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['coauthor']):"NA";
$abstractreg = isset($_POST['abstract']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['abstract']):"NA";
$nameconreg = isset($_POST['namecon']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['namecon']):"NA";
$areareg = isset($_POST['area']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['area']):"NA";
$datereg = isset($_POST['date']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']):"NA";
$startpagereg = isset($_POST['startpage']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['startpage']):"NA";
$endpagereg = isset($_POST['endpage']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['endpage']):"NA";
$countryreg = isset($_POST['country']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['country']):"NA";

// Updating the values of Table "Project"
$papertitlereg = isset($_POST['papertitle']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['papertitle']):"NA";
$projname1reg = isset($_POST['projname1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projname1']):"NA";
$projid1reg = isset($_POST['projid1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projid1']):"NA";
$projcont1reg = isset($_POST['projcont1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projcont1']):"NA";
$projname2reg = isset($_POST['projname2']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projname2']):"NA";
$projid2reg = isset($_POST['projid2']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projid2']):"NA";
$projcont2reg = isset($_POST['projcont2']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['projcont2']):"NA";

// Updating the values of Table "Journal"
$issnreg = isset($_POST['issn']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['issn']):"NA";
$jtitlereg = isset($_POST['jtitle']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['jtitle']):"NA";
$imfacreg = isset($_POST['imfac']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['imfac']):"NA";
$isbnreg = isset($_POST['isbn']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['isbn']):"NA";
$scireg = isset($_POST['sci']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['sci']):"NA";
$locationreg = isset($_POST['location']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']):"NA";
$issuereg = isset($_POST['issue']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['issue']):"NA";
$volumereg = isset($_POST['volume']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['volume']):"NA";

// Create Local variable
$taken = "false";
$database = "publication";
$password = "";
$username = "root";

// Main if statement
//if($userreg && $passreg){

// Connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password,$database);

                if ($con->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
                }


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `paper` VALUES('$typereg', '$ptitlereg','$fauthorreg','$coauthorreg','$abstractreg' ,'$nameconreg', '$areareg','$datereg', '$startpagereg', '$endpagereg','$projid1reg','$countryreg' )") or die("Strange Error");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `journal` VALUES('$issnreg', '$ptitlereg','$imfacreg','$isbnreg','$scireg' ,'$locationreg', '$issuereg','$volumereg')") or die("Strange Error");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `project` VALUES( '$ptitlereg','$projname1reg','$projid1reg','$projcont1reg' ,'$projname2reg', '$projid2reg','$projcont2reg')") or die("Strange Error");

echo "Account Created";

mysqli_close($con);

header('Location: home.php');

 //} else {

//echo "You need to have both a username and password";
//}


?>
```

Comment: I tried, For the first time, its working fine but for the second time, its giving "Strange Error".

Comment: @user3363895 Could you please post your database code. Also, please check whether you have defined any field in database table as unique or primary key.

Comment: I checked my database and the error was in the primary key thing. Thanks it worked now.

Comment: if your problem is solved, you should update the content of your question above, and tell it verbatim that 'EDIT. The problem is fixed.'